# Rollapply with expanding window in R

Tags: r, expand, rollapply

Let's say I have a simple toy vector in R like:

```
x = seq(1:10);x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I want to use the rollapply function from zoo package but in a different way.Rollapply calculates a function from a vector x with width argument to be a rolling window.I want instead of rolling to be expanding.There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829919/rollapply-with-growing-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190604/rollapply-for-cumulative-window) but they don't help me with my problem.

For example what I want to calculate the sum of the first observations of vector x and then expand the window but by 2.

Doing so I did :

```
rollapplyr(x, seq_along(x) ,sum,by=2,partial = 5,fill=NA)
 [1] NA NA NA NA 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

or replace the NA's

```
na.locf0(rollapplyr(x, 5 ,sum,by=2,partial = 5,fill=NA))
[1] NA NA NA NA 15 15 25 25 35 35
```

But what I ideally want as a result is:

```
 [1] NA NA NA NA 15 15 28 28 45 45
```

Imagine that my dataset is huge (contains 2500 time series observations) and the function is some econometric - statistical model not a simple one like the sum that I use here.

How can I do it? Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
x <- seq(10)

expandapply <- function(x, start, by, FUN){
  # set points to apply function up to
  checkpoints <- seq(start, length(x), by)
  # apply function to all windows
  vals <- sapply(checkpoints, function(i) FUN(x[seq(i)]))
  # fill in numeric vector at these points (assumes output is numeric)
  out <- replace(rep(NA_real_, length(x)), checkpoints, vals)
  # forward-fill the gaps
  zoo::na.locf(out, na.rm = FALSE)
}


expandapply(x, start = 5, by = 2, FUN = sum)
#>  [1] NA NA NA NA 15 15 28 28 45 45
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: awesome answer.thank you.I thought that there will be a simple adjustment in  rollpply function though

Answer (score 1):

Define `nonNA` as the positions which should not be NA.  You can change x and `nonNA` to whatever you need.

Then assign w a vector of widths to use using zero for those components which are to be NA.  Finally apply na.locf0.

(The two extreme cases are that if `nonNA` is `seq_along(x)` so that all elements are not to be NA'd out then this is the same as `rollapplyr(x, seq_along(x), sum)` and if `nonNA` is `c()` so that there are no non-NAs then it returns all NAs.)

```
library(zoo)

x <- 1:10
nonNA <- seq(5, length(x), 2)

w <- ifelse(seq_along(x) %in% nonNA, seq_along(x), 0)
na.locf0(rollapplyr(x, w, function(x) if (length(x)) sum(x) else NA, fill=NA))
##  [1] NA NA NA NA 15 15 28 28 45 45
```

Another way is to use a list for the`width=` argument of `rollapply` whose components contain the offsets.  `x` and `nonNA` are from above.

```
L <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(x) if (x %in% nonNA) -seq(x-1, 0))
na.locf0(rollapplyr(x, L, sum, fill = NA))
##  [1] NA NA NA NA 15 15 28 28 45 45
```

### Update

Simplified solution and added second approach.